# How get a content of script tag if it length more than 10000?

Tags: google-chrome

I try read teaxt of script tag, but i don't recive it fully if it length more than 10000. For example:

```
$('script')[0].innerText
```

Result:
 http://savepic.ru/13148939.png

commented on Administration task REL…" - it in end of result

Added: If i change content (f.e. $('script').text($('script').text()+'aaaa') then return full text

Comment: you can use right click and choose `view page source`, it should show the html code, if there is a script tag 10000+ it should show it all.

Comment: Yes, i know, but i want use it in my scripts.

Comment: is there a reason for you doing this?  this seems unproductive, it is easier just copy it to text editor.

Comment: I want to make chrome-extension. Sometimes sites stores data in inline-scripts (f.e. gmail). I need scrap it and use in content-script.